# Python / NumPy type hints drives me nuts

Tags: python, numpy, type-hinting

Can't figure out how to type the return type!!!

```py
def sensor_data_to_numpy(data: Union[SensorData, List[SensorData]]) -> np.ndarray:
    if isinstance(data, List):
        return np.array([[item.label, item.sample, item.file, *item.matrix] for item in data])
    else:
        return np.array([data.label, data.sample, data.file, *data.matrix])
```

I also tried with npt.NDArray but again - I can't figure out the right syntax.
However, it should return a tuple like this: `(str, str, str, List[float])`

Comment: Actually, they are not so important, you can ignore them for now, they did not impact anything except documentation.

Comment: But it doesn't return a `tuple` at all, it returns a `numpy.ndarray`, which seems to be what you are annotating it with. Why are you saying it returns a tuple??

Comment: @mrvol they can be, this depends on the QA you are using for you project

Comment: As an aside, you should really only be using `List` for type hints, not for `isinstance` checks (although, it *does* work). In any case, it is deprecated and will be removed in the future

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga this is from official documentation `The Python runtime does not enforce function and variable type annotations. They can be used by third party tools such as type checkers, IDEs, linters, etc.` https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: @mrvol yes, that doesn't contradict what I'm saying at all. In fact, that supports it. Your QA suite for your project may involve something like `mypy`.

Comment: Looks like the function will return a 1d or 2d string dtype array.  Even if `data.matrix` contains floats, making an array with `str` elements will result in a `str` dtype for all values.